# Rails2 update_without_callbacks monkeypatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I know monkey patches are bad, but I have the following patch for `update_without_callbacks` for my Rails2 app, but I am having a hard time porting it to rails3 as that method no longer exists in Rails3.

Here is the definition:

```
def update_without_callbacks(attribute_names = @attributes.keys)
   if changed?
     update_creating_new_version_row(attribute_names)
     update_shared_columns
   else
     Rails.logger.info("this record unchanged; skipping update")
   end

   true
end
```

Please suggest as to how i should go about porting it to Rails3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be replaced by:

```
save(:callbacks => false)
```